# Create data frame with month start and end in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a pandas dataframe from a given start and end date:

```py
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd
start_date = "2020-05-17"
end_date = "2020-07-23"
```

For each row in this dataframe, I should have the start day and end day of the month, so the expected output is:

```py
start       end         month   year
2020-05-17  2020-05-31  May     2020
2020-06-01  2020-06-30  June    2020
2020-07-01  2020-07-23  July    2020
```

I know I have to loop over each month between the interval created by `start_date` and `end_date`. While I know how to extract the last day in a date:

```
def last_day(date: str):
    return pd.Timestamp(date) + MonthEnd(1)
```

I'm stuck over how to run this over the interval. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pd.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) and [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
start = pd.to_datetime([start_date] + pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='MS').tolist())
end = pd.to_datetime(pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='M').tolist() + [end_date])
month = start.strftime('%B')
year = start.year

df = pd.DataFrame({'start': start, 'end': end, 'month': month, 'year': year})
```

Output:

```
>>> df
       start        end month  year
0 2020-05-17 2020-05-31   May  2020
1 2020-06-01 2020-06-30  June  2020
2 2020-07-01 2020-07-23  July  2020
```

Answer (score 2):

You can transform the output from `.isocalendar()`:

```py
r = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq="D").isocalendar()
out = (
    r.assign(month=r.index.month)
    .reset_index()
    .groupby(["year", "month"])["index"]
    .agg(("first", "last"))
    .reset_index()
)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
   year  month      first       last
0  2020      5 2020-05-17 2020-05-31
1  2020      6 2020-06-01 2020-06-30
2  2020      7 2020-07-01 2020-07-23
```

---

To have string month names:

```py
out = out.rename(columns={'first':'start', 'last':'end'})
out['month'] = pd.to_datetime(out['month'], format='%m').dt.strftime('%b')
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
   year month      start        end
0  2020   May 2020-05-17 2020-05-31
1  2020   Jun 2020-06-01 2020-06-30
2  2020   Jul 2020-07-01 2020-07-23
```